# Do I need a transit to pass through Cuba to Bahamas?

Tags: transit, nigerian-citizens

Is transit visa required for a Nigerian passport holder traveling to Bahamas with Bahamas tourist visa and flying 3 different flights from Nigeria to the final destination

Nigeria to Dubai, (Emirates)
Dubai to Cuba (Aeroflot)
Cuba to Bahamas (Air Bahamas)

Comment: There are no direct flights between Dubai and Havana (or any other airport in Cuba), and if there were, Aeroflot would not be operating them. I assume you have a stop in Sheremetyevo between Dubai and Havana?

Comment: @Calchas good catch; that totally eluded me. I'll add generic Timatic link so that OP can do his own, corrected search.

Answer (score 2):

According to [TIMATIC,](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/6ZR8fmciScUf0rjMJ1wJh0QViJDHux3CwXoxeyivDGw) for citizens of Nigeria, transiting without a visa is possible for holders of confirmed onward tickets for a maximum transit time of 24 hours, and provided that they do not leave the international transit area of the airport.  A visa would be required should you need to transit between Dubai International Airport (DXB) and Dubai Al Maktoum International (DWC).

For Cuba, Nigerian passport holders are visa exempt for up to 72 hours with proof of the onward flight and the necessary documents for the next destination.

If, as @Calchas has pointed out, your itinerary has additional transit points, you can use the [Timatic tool](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) to check requirements yourself.

Timatic is what is used by airlines to verify passengers travel document requirements for their destination and any transit.