# How can an Bangladeshi citizen travel to Trinidad and Tobago from Bangladesh without needing a transit visa along the way?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, transit

I would like to travel Trinidad and Tobago and few other Caribbean. Most of the connecting flights are going through USA , Canada which I need transit visa.

I have found some route not sure is gonna work or not.

Dhaka To Istanbul To Havana ( turkish airlines) and from Havana to Port of Spain ( copa airlines ) 2 ticket will be separate I'll have only hand bag no checked baggage. So in that case is it possible to get boarding pass from havana airport inside transit area ?
Istanbul and Havana both I don't need transit visa.
Thanks

Comment: When are you looking to travel? Havana and Trinidad & Tobago airports remain closed AFAIK

Comment: Also:  Turkish Airlines and Copa Airlines have a codeshare agreement, so you might actually be able to buy the itinerary on a single ticket. (And it's generally a good idea to avoid split tickets if you can.)

Comment: But you need a visa for Cuba!

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I'll amend my comment.

Comment: Likely transit points other than the US are ex-French colonies, Mexico, Cuba, and Panama. (However, note comments that some of these airports are closed, and some countries require visas for Bangladeshis.) Look at the webpages for the airports in Trinidad and Tobago, and the other places you'd like to visit, and see where flights to those places originate. Here's a similar question from a Nigerian going to the Bahamas who faces the same don't-go-to-the-US challenge: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131077/travel-from-nigeria-to-bahamas-avoiding-transit-in-us-uk-and-canada

Comment: @Traveller POS is open. At least, commercial flights are arriving and departing, which would suggest the airport is open...

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any itinerary that would not require a visa to transit some country. I suspect no such itinerary currently exists, especially with many flights cancelled due to COVID-19.

Your proposed itinerary requires a visa from Cuba. Yours is one of the few nationalities for which Cuba requires a full visa and not just an inexpensive tourist card, and the itinerary also requires passing immigration.

Consider getting a C-1 transit visa from the USA. This is generally easier to obtain than a tourist/business visa. It will also let you exit the airport during your layover. And most of the cheap flights for DAC-POS will transit the USA. Having such a visa can also help you build a travel history and possibly make it easier to obtain other visas later.

You might also consider getting a DATV (direct airside transit visa) from the UK. You can then transit the UK and fly via the UK and Barbados, as Barbados does not require visas for Bangladeshi citizens. Depending on the day of the week you fly, this may be the cheapest option. But the DATV will not allow for exiting the airside transit area.

Comment: It looks like Turkish Airlines is resuming TK800 from Istanbul to Panama City (with a stopover in Bogotá) twice a week, on Wednesdays and Sundays, starting on November 1.  This would work if the OP can get this itinerary.  However, while I can buy a ticket on the flight on its own, I can't get Turkish Airlines' website to include it in a DAC–POS itinerary;  there may be some arcane reason Turkish Airlines won't allow it.